# Pod not writing on a local path

Tags: kubernetes, docker-volume, persistent-storage

I'm new with containers and kubernetes.
What I'm trying to do is to create a pod with access to a local directory.

I have followed the directions from:
[configure persistent volume storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/)

Created my Persistent Volume, Persistent Volume Claim and my pod.

The problem is that the tomcat is not able to write on the shared directory

This is the Persistent Volume:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv-webapp6
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/opt/test_tomcat/app"
```

This is the Persistent Volume Claim:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc-webapp6
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

This is the tomcat Pod I'm trying to create:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: webapp6
spec:
  containers:
  - image: tomcat:8.0
    name: webapp6
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
        name: webapp6
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: pvc-webapp6
```

Its a bit obvious, but this the error on the pod.

> [root@testserver webapp6-test]# kubectl exec -it webapp6  -- /bin/bash 
>   root@webapp6:/usr/local/tomcat# mkdir /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample 
>   mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample’: Permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your PVC yaml file where you're not specifying the `storageClassName`. Hence the PV and PVC couldn't bound to each other. Please replace the PVC yaml file with the following file:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
   name: pvc-webapp6
spec:
   storageClassName: manual
   accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
   resources:
      requests:
         storage: 3Gi
```

Now everything should work. Hope this helps.

I quickly used your yaml to deploy pod and everything is working fine at my end:

```
[root@Master admin]# kubectl exec -it webapp6 bash
root@webapp6:/usr/local/tomcat#  mkdir /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample 
root@webapp6:/usr/local/tomcat# touch /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample/a
root@webapp6:/usr/local/tomcat# ls /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample/
a
```

Now when I look at host, I can see the newly created `a` file

```
[root@Master admin]# ls /opt/test_tomcat/app/sample/
a
```

So, at least yaml files are working fine.

Comment: Actually, I was using the storageClassName: manual. I put the wrong PVC yaml on the question. I have updated it now.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further. Because I am able to write inside the pod at /usr/local/tomcat/webapps and those files are reflected at  /opt/test_tomcat/app..

Comment: When tomcat deploys the sample.war that is inside  /opt/test_tomcat/app, it needs to create the sample directory with the application deploy. Its to able to deploy/create the sample directory.

Comment: Its Not able to create/deploy the sample application inside the /opt/test_tomcat/app directory. Sorry, I'm not able to edit my previous comment :S

Comment: I have edited my ans. Yamls are working fine. I will again have a look about what is wrong there

Comment: I will try to recreate it from the scratch.